# Draw a graph of a PyTorch model which takes a packed tensor as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, tensorboard

I defined my neural network to take a packed sequence as input, and then pads it a

```
def forward(self, x):
        y, _ = self.rnn(x)
        output ,lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(y, batch_first = True)
        out = [output[e, i-1,:].unsqueeze(0) for e, i in enumerate(lengths)]
        out = torch.cat(out, dim = 0)
        return out
```

And tried to make a graph of the network.

```
tb = torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter()
tb.add_graph(model, input) # input is a packed sequence tensor
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: MyRNN.forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure if it's possible to use the packed sequence here.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the reason of the error but could you try defining forward function as `def forward(self, x, *args)`?